# Unable to install any add-in for Excel Desktop in MacOS Catalina (Microsoft Excel cannot access the file)

Tags: excel, macos, office-addins, office-store

I get an error when I try to install an add-in for MacOS Catalina (10.15.5) and Excel for Mac (16.37 2005 1002)

As a sample, you can try Microsoft People Graph.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that is not a programming question because you are trying to install third-party software, I'd suggest posting this to the https://superuser.com/ web site instead. People will vote for closing it.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, I have duplicated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the error, I opened the My Add-ins dialog and after clicking the Refresh button the add-in appeared on the list. Then I was able to add it.

[image]